# How to add a Scala List or Set in Cassandra?

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, playframework-2.6

My Cassandra's table schema is

```
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    a text,
    d text,
    h list<text>,
    i  list<blob>,
    p  text,
    t set<text>,
    title text
```

I want to add data from the following `case class`

`Data(Some(b7a8bc92-0191-4d76-9c11-df8301e20911),d,List(d),List(1),d,Set(d),d,d)`

To add the data, I have written the following `QueryBuilder` code

```
def insertValues(tableName:String, model:Data):Insert = {
    QueryBuilder.insertInto(tableName).value("id",model.id.get) 
      .value("a",model.a)
      .value("d",model.d)
      .value("h",model.h) 
      .value("i",model.i)
      .value("p",model.p)
      .value("t",model.t)
      .value("title",model.title)
      .ifNotExists(); 
  }
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Errorcom.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Value 3 of type class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon does not correspond to any CQL3 type

I am probably messing up between data types used in `Scala` and `Cassandra` but I don't know how to correct this. Eg. one issue I see is I don't know how to convert `String` to `blob` used by field `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to use functions from `scala.collection.JavaConversions._`. The working code snippet is

```
  .value("image",seqAsJavaList(model.image))
  .value("tags",setAsJavaSet(model.tags))
```

Comment: You can also use java-driver-scala-extras package (compile it yourself): https://github.com/datastax/java-driver-scala-extras